# .htaccess redirect to different domain only if URL is invalid

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create a .htaccess rule to redirect users from one domain to the other, but this should happen only if the original URL does not exist. For example:

- `www.domain.com/100` to `www.otherdomain.com/PersonalPages/100`
- `www.domain.com/150` to `www.otherdomain.com/PersonalPages/150`

Now, I don't have a page/file named 100 or 150, so that's why it should redirect, but if user enters "www.domain.com" I do have "index.php" and should stay in "www.domain.com" and not try to go to "www.otherdomain.com/PersonalPages/index.php" (or any other if page exist in my www.domain.com)

I know I can create a simple 301 redirect, but the numbers in the URL are the IDs of users and that number will grow on a daily basis so I can't be adding lines of redirects to my .htaccess for each new user.

Is there a 404 code I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/PersonalPages/$1
```

`^` and `$` mark the beginning/end of the url, `[0-9]+` stands for one or more numbers between 0 and 9.